# words in htmls are slightly moving after this javascript.

Tags: javascript, android, html

I never worked with javascript, I'm an android developer, but the person ordered an application gave me htmls whith javascript, with which I didn't have any experience.
This is the function that should highlight words. The problem is on some devices the words are slightly moving when they are highlighted (on some they don't). How can I eliminate this problem?
Thanx in advance.

```
function lightWord(node, start, end, nWord) {
    var rng = document.createRange();
    rng.setStart(node, start);
    rng.setEnd(node, end);
    var outerSpan = document.createElement('span');
    outerSpan.setAttribute("id", "curWord");
    outerSpan.nWordNum = nWord;
    outerSpan.hideStep = 0;
    outerSpan.style.position = 'relative';
    rng.surroundContents( outerSpan );

    var innerSpan = document.createElement('span');
    innerSpan.className = 'inner';
    innerSpan.style.position = 'absolute';
    innerSpan.style.backgroundColor = '#BF9A8D';
    innerSpan.style.width = outerSpan.offsetWidth+'px';
    innerSpan.style.height = outerSpan.offsetHeight+'px';
    innerSpan.style.top = '0';
    innerSpan.style.left = '0';
    innerSpan.style.zIndex = '-1';
    outerSpan.appendChild(innerSpan);
}
```

Comment: Could you create jsfiddle with that and add some html?

Comment: I did, but it works only from android code, so it won't work as it is